# Can we create a new folder inside a standard deploy folder in JBoss?

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, directory

I have several libraries that our project requires. I would like to separate our projects with other existing jar/war/ear files that already exist in Jboss server/default/deploy folder.

I am thinking of creating a new folder inside that deploy folder and putting all our project files/dependency jars in that.

Does JBoss pick them up automatically? If not, what is the setting to tell JBoss to pick up the files in that folder?

Jboss version 4.2.2-GA.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your deployment scanner config, which is kept in `server/<profile>/conf/jboss-service.xml`. The relevant part is:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner" name="jboss.deployment:type=DeploymentScanner,flavor=URL">
  ...    
  <!-- URLs are comma separated and resolve relative to the server home URL unless the given path is absolute. [...] -->
  <attribute name="URLs">
    deploy/
  </attribute>    
  ...    
  <!-- Indicates if the scanner should recursively scan directories that contain no "." in their names. [...] -->
  <attribute name="RecursiveSearch">True</attribute>
</mbean>
```